# BRANCH env variable is undefined using gatsby cloud

Tags: environment-variables, gatsby

> **Read-only variables**
>   These variables are pre-defined for both Builds and Preview environments. They are set automatically and cannot be changed. You can reference them in your `gatsby-config.js` or anywhere else you would normally reference an environment variable.
>
> - `BRANCH:` The name of the current git branch. Useful for swapping environment variables depending on the branch.
> - `CI:` Always `true`.
> - `GATSBY_CLOUD:` Always `true`. Useful for checking if your build is running on Gatsby Cloud.

This is what gatsby cloud [doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/managing-environment-variables/#read-only-variables) said.

but when I print out console for the `process.env.BRANCH`, it was `undefined` while `process.env.GATSBY_CLOUD` is `true` as expected.

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

In the build process, Webpack removes all environment variables that do not start with `GATSBY_` you can use the `gatsby-plugin-env-variables` plugin or this snippet in gatsby-node.js is enough.

```js
const BRANCH = process.env.BRANCH || 'master';

  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    plugins: [
      plugins.define({
        'process.env.BRANCH': JSON.stringify(BRANCH),
      }),
    ],
  });
```